# Chromium randomly cannot load pages

Tags: browser, chromium

I have a Realme 1 with Android 9. No matter what Chromium I use, sometimes the pages don't load, the loading bar being a bit filled. This happens randomly. It even happens with about:blank. I have faced this problem for years with Bromite, Kiwi Browser, Brave etc. The Webview browsers do not have this problem. I do not have Chrome installed.

Comment: Whats your phone specification ?

Comment: @RohitGupta the post has mentioned "Realme 1 with Android 9", so I'm not sure what information you want to know more about without mentioning it specifically...

Comment: @RohitGupta 4GB RAM 64GB Storage. More info at: https://m.gsmarena.com/realme_1-9200.php if you want to be more specific.